# Does the Programmer's Dvorak keyboard layout work on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I see that Mountain Lion has come preinstalled with 4 versions of the [Dvorak keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard). I do not think these versions are "Programmer's Dvorak." I found a version of this layout here: http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/

After installing it I had no luck finding it in my System Preferences. Does anyone know if this layout is available under Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to work on 10.8, but you have to log out and back in after running the installer.

Answer (score 0):

You should run
`sudo rm -f /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le*`
in order to invalidate layout caches, and then you will see Programmer's layout in the list.